# Is there a way to handle a ThreadAbortException from a System.Threading.Timer?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, threadabortexception

I have a `System.Threading.Timer` that I am using to periodically update data from SQL Server.  Occasionally, the timer's thread aborts and I see ThreadAbortExceptions being raised.

Right now, we handle these exceptions in the `Global.asax.cs` Application_Error method/handler.

However, I'd like to handle this error closer to the actual timer, so I can actually do something more about it other than just log it.

But it is not clear to me - how can I watch for these events on the Timer?

EDIT: The actual exception I am getting:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 ) at 
SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer() at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte() at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at S
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at 
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at 
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) ...
```

Comment: I wonder what *other logic* you might want to apply than logging the exception in this case.

Comment: You'd better find out how it is getting aborted, it is certainly not normal.  Thread.Abort() cannot do this, unless you call it within the callback itself.  The only other scenario I can think of it that it is getting aborted by the host.  You don't want to stop or filter that.

Comment: @Darin I would create a new instance of the Timer with the same callback/frequency, etc.

Comment: Is it possible that these are being generated by a response.redirect?

Comment: @Conrad No, this process is independent of the actual request/response cycle.  Plus, we don't actually do those anywhere anyway (and yes, I am aware that ThreadAbortException is normal behavior for Response.Redirect)

Comment: @Hans I would *love* to figure out what is causing it.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to track that down though.  As seen in my edit above, it's related to SQL Server communications, but I thought those threw their own exceptions (such as TimeoutException)

Comment: @Matt I'm having a hard time reconciling the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) and your comment. An error handler that is defined in the Global.asax file will only catch errors that occur during processing of requests by the ASP.NET runtime

Comment: Yes, that's a likely place for the thread to get aborted, it is waiting for a response from the dbase provider.  That takes a while.  Look at the *other* threads, one of them is calling Thread.Abort().  Assuming it isn't the host.

Comment: @Conrad I'm not sure what to tell you.  It is possible the Timer is not created until the first request to the webserver, but the timer itself is executing periodically on it's own after that.

Comment: @Hans So, if I understand correctly, you are saying that Thread.Abort() is getting called from somewhere else, and that just happens the be where, in the stack, the Thread is currently sitting?  Are there any components in Timers or ExecuteReader that call Thread.Abort? Because there is not a single instance of Thread.Abort anywhere in our code.

Comment: Use Debug + Windows + Threads to find out what other threads are doing.